# PHP Carbon - Create a date in future relative to current time

Tags: php, php-carbon

Imagine we have the day (of week) and the time of an event ( that is in the future ) :

```
$day = "Wednesday";
$time = "13:00";
```

And we want to create a Carbon date for that, but it has to be relative to current time :

```
$carbon = new Carbon();
```

For example if `$carbon` is `Tuesday, 2017-01-17 09:00`,
the `$event` date that we create should be `Wednesday, 2017-01-18 13:00`

In other words, the `$event` is a date that is taking place in the next 7 days. We don't have it's year, month and other data, but we do know it's day of week and the time.

Comment: `Carbon::parse('next ' . $day)` ??

Comment: @iam-decoder Nice! I didn't know about that. I have seen `first day of` in the Carbon docs but didn't know about that keyword. Where can I find the rest? By the way, can we use `$time` in the `parse` string?

Comment: @iam-decoder Alright I got it working. $time can be added in parse string as well. If you post your comment as an answer I can accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to use something like:

```
Carbon::parse('next ' . $day)
```

and you can also throw the `$time` part in there somewhere too but can't remember exactly how right now.